# Laravel Model Equivalent query

Tags: php, laravel

What might be the equivalent Query of the following SQL query?

```
select intro_home_use, count(*) from details group by intro_home_use;
```

I achieved what I needed using DB facade

```
DB::select('select intro_home_use, count(*) from details group by intro_home_use');
```

Just started working in laravel.
Thank you!

Comment: try this `Detail::select('intro_home_use')->withCount('*')->groupBy('intro_home_use')->get();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this:

```php
$result = Details::select('intro_home_use', \DB::raw('count(*) as count'))
          ->groupBy('intro_home_use')
          ->get();
```

This'll give you something like this:

```
[
    {
        intro_home_use: "xxx",
        count: 1
    },
    {
        intro_home_use: "yyy",
        count: 2
    }
]
```

Comment: Got exactly what I wanted. Thank you. However, I think you missed a closing bracket for the select ie after count').
Awesome Thank you

Comment: Please edit that and I will accept your answer as 'The Answer'

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your details model setup you can do something like this:

```
Details::select('intro_home_use')->groupBy('intro_home_use')->count();
```

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries.

Edit: As pointed out by @The_Alpha this will not return what you are after. Their answer is correct.

Comment: This'll give the count, i.e: `1`.